# Ionic 4 string to html

Tags: angular, ionic4

Hello I am trying to make a calendar and show it created by div but my probleme is when i call my data to my app, app write string and don't take the html inside it.

This is my **home.ts**:

```
calendarloop(tmp = 1) {
        for (let cpt = 0; cpt < 6; cpt++ ) {
           this.calendar += '<div class="row"><div class="col-2"></div>';
            for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                this.calendar += '<div class="col-1 calendar">' + tmp + '</div>';
            } tmp++;
            this.calendar += '<div class="col-2"></div></div>';
        }
}
```

This is my **home.html**:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-1 calendar">D</div>
        <div class="col-1 calendar">L</div>
        <div class="col-1 calendar">M</div>
        <div class="col-1 calendar">M</div>
        <div class="col-1 calendar">J</div>
        <div class="col-1 calendar">V</div>
        <div class="col-1 calendar">S</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
  {{ calendar }}
```

Can someone have a solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is the innerHTML Angular tag

```
<div [innerHTML]="string html code"></div>
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that this allows for __XSS__ vulnerability to be exploited. [According to the docs](https://angular.io/guide/security)

Comment: Note that it's quite useless to answer obvious direct duplicates if your answer doesn't bring something specific